# Find multiple occurences of same string

Tags: ubuntu, sed, grep

In a range of files, I want to see which line has atleast 4 times the same occurence of the same word. This word can be any word.

So
input:

```
a a a b b e e e
o o o o p p p y y y
w r r r u u i i o o r
x x o o i i p p z z y y
```

Output:

```
o o o o p p p y y y
w r r r u u i i o o r
```

What I have tried at the moment is to make sure that sentences are put separate, ready to be processed basically.

```
cat * |
    tr '\n' ' '|
    sed 's/[.!?;"]/ & /g' |
    sed 's/[.!?]/&\n/g'|
    grep -E -w '\b([[:alnum:]]*)\{4*\}\b'
```

But my grep doesn't get anything, so how do I get that Grep only prints out all sentences which contain a word which occurs atleast 4 times in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, you can use a PCRE regex like

```sh
grep -P '\b(\w+)\b(.*\b\1\b){3}'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQCb5W/1).

Test in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS:

[image]

**Details**

- `\b(\w+)\b` - a whole word (captured in Group 1) (`\b` is a word boundary and `\w` matches letters, digits or underscores)
- `(.*\b\1\b){3}` - three occurrences (`{3}`) of any text followed with the same value as in Group 1 (as `\1` is an inline backreference to Group 1  value) as a whole word (again, `\b` word boundaries are used.)

Comment: You can simplify by putting the word bounds in the group: `grep -E '(\b\w\b)(.*\1){3}'`. Unless there's an edge case I haven't thought of.

Comment: @wjandrea The capturing group only keeps the value, not the pattern. So, `\1` is unaware of the fact if the string it holds was captured as a whole word or not. We need all the word boundaries I  used in the pattern.

Comment: Ah, I see, if you use input like `o do to moe`, mine matches it (false positive), yours doesn't.

Comment: I am also getting false positives with yours solution @WiktorStribiżew. It most likely has to do with the first word boundary, I would say. ```en vrouwen gelijk voor de wet en maken we geen``` is one of my results, but the word *en* does not pop up separately 4 times. It does if you count the *en* inside of the words.

Comment: @Hooiberg12 Ok, there seems a bug with the word boundary implementation in the POSIX ERE syntax in the GNU `grep`. Please switch to the PCRE engine using `-P` option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [link](https://file.io/fJlJUr2kjFzy) is one of the files I am using.

Comment: @Hooiberg12 I understand, just use `-P`, not `-E`.

Comment: Ah yes this seems to work. Thank you for the solution to my problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew here's one discussion related to that bug: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579889/why-doesnt-this-sed-command-replace-the-3rd-to-last-and

Answer (score 2):

Awk is another possibility that will do the same thing with a simple array using the elements as counters without needing a REGEX (though the answer by @WiktorStribizew is the efficient way to go). For example, using the `a[]` array with the field as the index, the value at that index is incremented on each occurrence and when any one field (word) reaches 4 occurrences the line is printed and you skip to the next record.

```
awk '{delete a; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (++a[$i]==4) {print $0; next}}' file
```

(`delete a` simply deletes the array before each records is processed)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '{delete a; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (++a[$i]==4) {print $0; next}}' file
o o o o p p p y y y
w r r r u u i i o o r
```